# Output printed in R code block in org-mode when it shouldn't be

Tags: r, emacs, org-mode, ess

I just upgraded to org 9.3.6 and now my R code blocks aren't working as expected. For example, I have this simple code block,

```
#+BEGIN_SRC R :session
  mtcars1 <- mtcars
#+END_SRC
```

I don't expect to see any output as I am saving `mtcars` as `mtcars1`, so R shouldn't return anything. However, I see this instead,

[image]
So, it's running

```
print(mtcars1)
```

Why? I don't expect/want to see any output especially with larger data frames as it chokes emacs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks you are using the default value of `:results value` in your org source header.  That can be changed on a case-by-case basis with

```
#+begin_src R :session :results output
mtcars1 <- mtcars 
#+end_src
```

or, change the default in your org (or ess/R) init configuration

```
(setq org-babel-default-header-args:R '((:results . "output")))
```

Comment: Thanks, this works. Do you happen to know how I can get multiple output in a code block? For example, how can I have the output from `head(mtcars$am)` and `head(mtcars$carb)` show up if they're both in the same block? Right now, it'll just show `head(mtcars$carb)`. I am guessing this has to do with `:results`. Can you point me to where you found this info on the web?

Comment: see the org manual: https://orgmode.org/manual/Results-of-Evaluation.html.  To print multiple values you could do something like `cat(mtcars$am, mtcars$carb, sep='\n')`, or put values in a list object

Comment: actually, for multiple output you should be able to just enter the `head(mtcars@carb); head(mtcars$am)` -- that works fine for me, as the stdout is just being captured, so normal output should work fine